# Unix shell: Turn file with directory names to ':' separated classpath

Tags: java, shell, unix, java-5

I use Java5 and I don't want to point each .jar file in Classpath so I've tried to write small shell script:

```
find $LIB_DIR -name '*.jar' -print > /tmp/classpath
CP= 
cat /tmp/classpath | while read line
do 
CP=$CP:$line
done 
rm -f /tmp/classpath
```

But this is not work - $CP variable is empty.

As a result $CP should be single string with pathes delimited by ':'

Is anyone knows what is wrong here and how to correctly concatenate all file's lines to one string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your while loop is in a sub-shell, so no variables will be passed back to the main shell.  You want to do something like this anyway:

```
CP=$(find $LIB_DIR -name '*.jar' -print | tr '\n' ':')
```

That'll do what you want all on one line.

Comment: A sed s/:$// can be added to remove the trailing colon.

Comment: Maybe you can mark it as a correct answer... give Steve his due

Comment: when run  CP=$(find ../lib -name '*.jar' -print | tr '\n' ':' |  sed s/:$// ) after sed we get empty string. If type just [echo "a::a:" | sed s/:$//] this works

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the while loop runs in a separate shell instance and the local variable in it (`$CP`) isn't available in the outer shell.

Something like

```
while read line; do
    CP="$CP:$line"
done < /tmp/classpath
```

should work. But note that `$CP` ends up with a colon as first character then so it needs some post-processing.

Moreover you should make use of `mktemp` otherwise you could be tricked into overwriting files if someone puts a symlink at `/tmp/classpath`.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear that said Uwe Kleine-König and Steve Baker while-do-done block is not subshell by its nature but because of pipe use in this code block

```
cat /tmp/classpath | while read line
do 
CP=$CP:$line
done
```

From [Bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash): "Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)."

More about [subshells](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/processtree).

See also [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760640/left-side-of-pipe-is-the-subshell) about pipe and subshells.

[enter link description here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/processtree)