# Losing environment in while loop

Tags: bash

A fun little bash teaser to which I'd love an explanation.

Two loop constructs I would have though are identical, clearly are not.  Seems there's some difference in piping vs redirecting when doing a `while` loop.

**Input File**

Given this sample file called `values.txt` with this content:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**Piping** to while

```
$ value=0; cat values.txt | while read var; do value=`expr $value + $var`; done
$ echo $value
0
```

**Redirecting** to while

```
$ value=0; while read var; do value=`expr $value + $var`; done < values.txt
$ echo $value
21
```

To be brief, clearly in the first version each iteration of the `while` loop executes effectively as `()` and in the second each iteration iterates as `{}`

The question is not the difference between `()` and `{}`.  My question is what *causes* this difference in behavior for `while` loops?

Is there a logical reason they should behave differently or was it just a bad choice made early on that couldn't be changed for compatibility reasons?  Is it ever possible to pipe to `while` and get `{}` behavior?

Comment: In the first version, the while part starts in a subshell (because of the pipe). Therefore, $value does not change. In the second part, the while runs inside the current shell and $value is modified. Add an export in the subshell to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, @Gregor but the difference between shell `{}` and subshell `()` was not the question.  The question is why is one a shell and one a subshell.

Comment: Some material on subshell vs. pipe I've found in the meantime. Doesn't reach for a full answer yet.
http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/pipe-in-bash-can-be-a-trap
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760640/left-side-of-pipe-is-the-subshell

Comment: The difference isn't in the `while`; it's not a poor choice made early on - using a pipe starts a subprocess regardless of what you pipe it to, otherwise it wouldn't work. Basically you answered yourself: no you can't do what you want without exporting everything each time, and you don't need to because you have a solution already

Comment: @moopet that the pipe itself creates the subshell and this ultimately has nothing to do with the `while` loop is the perfect answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known problem and is well explained here:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

To quote the most explanatory part:

> Different shells exhibit different behaviors in this situation:
>
> - **BourneShell** creates a subshell when the input or output of anything
>     (loops, case etc..) but a simple command is redirected, either by
>     using a pipeline or by a redirection operator ('<', '>').
> - **BASH** creates a new process only if the loop is part of a pipeline.
> - **KornShell**
>     creates it only if the loop is part of a pipeline, but not if the loop
>     is the last part of it.
> - **POSIX** specifies the bash behaviour, but as
>     an extension allows any or all of the parts of the pipeline to run
>     without a subshell (thus permitting the KornShell behaviour, as well).

As for the last question: yes, it is possible in certain shells, and in bash only if you have bash >=4.2, and preceed your code with disabling job control and enabling lastpipe option with the following code: `set +m; shopt -s lastpipe`