# split a string delimited by a string in bash

Tags: string, bash, awk

I'm trying to split a string of this kind :

```
file1 -> file2
```

and expect to affect "file1" and "file2" to 2 variables.

I tried with IFS but it seems to work only for one character long (with IFS=" -> " I get "file1" and "> file2"...

Based on [this article](http://www.humbug.in/2010/bash-tricks-split-cut-a-string-with-multi-character-delimiters-using-awk/), I tried another approach :

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" -> "} {xxx}' <<< $f
```

The issue is that I don't succeed to affect $1 and $2 to a variable that I could use later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways:

```
str="file1 -> file2"

echo "Fast"
var1="${str% -> *}"
var2="${str#* -> }"
printf "%s=%s.\n" var1 "${var1}" var2 "${var2}"

echo "With cut"
var1="$(echo ${str}|cut -d" " -f1)"
var2="$(echo ${str}|cut -d" " -f3)"
printf "%s=%s.\n" var1 "${var1}" var2 "${var2}"

echo "With read"
read -r var1 arrow var2 <<< ${str}
```

Comment: Where did you find the one with read ? I don't find the documentation and `man read` doesn't help a lot...

Comment: I learned this somewhere on SO, maybe at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19052249/3220113.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **$()**:

```
VARIABLE="$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=" -> "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' <<< $f)"
```

You can assign the results to an array:

```
ARRAY=( $(awk 'BEGIN {FS=" -> "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' <<< $f) )
```

And extract the values as separate variables:

```
${ARRAY[0]}
${ARRAY[1]}
and so on...
```

And assign it to your variables.

Comment: I understand how I can print, but how can I use it later in the script ?