# Setting environment variables from two lines of output

Tags: bash

I have a external program (kind of an authentication token generator) that outputs two lines, two parts of my authentication.

```
$ get-auth
SomeAuthString1
SomeAuthString2
```

Then, I want to export these strings into an environment variable, say, `AUTH` and `PIN`.

I tried several things in bash, but nothing works.

For example, I can do:

```
get-auth | read -d$'\4' AUTH PIN
```

but it fails. AUTH and PIN remain unset. If I do

```
get-auth | paste -d\  -s | read AUTH PIN
```

it also fails. The only way I can get the data is by doing

```
get-auth | { read AUTH; read PIN; }
```

but obviously only in the subshell. Exporting from that has no result

A bit of research, and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760640/left-side-of-pipe-is-the-subshell) that might mean that I can't do that (reading a variable from something piped into a read). But I might be wrong. I also found that if I open a subshell with `{` before the read, the values are available in the subshell until I finish it with `}`.

Is there any way I can set environment variables from the two-line output? I obviously don't want to save that to a file, and I don't want to set up a FIFO just for that. Are those the only ways of getting that done?

Comment: Is something like: `authstrings=\`get-auth\`; export AUTH=$authstrings[0]; export PIN=$authstrings[1]` possible?

Comment: Note that `{...}` does not create a subshell, just a grouped command. It is, as you discovered, the *pipe* that creates the subshell.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bash` [process-substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), `<()` to achieve the same using the `read` command.

```
$ cat file
123
456
```

With using command-substitution properly you can retain the command output. Using `read` and `\n` as the de-limiter as;

```
$ read -r -d'\n' a b < <(cat file)
$ printf "%s %s\n" "$a" "$b"
123 456
```

Now the variables are available in the current shell, you can always `export` it.

Comment: `<(...)` is *process* substitution, not command substitution (which is `$(...)`).

Comment: @chepner : Too much of thinking while writing it. :) fixed now

Answer (score 0):

The subshell was the issue. I was able to make it work by doing:

```
read -d $'\4' AUTH PIN < <(get-auth)
```