# Shell script: while variable concatenation

Tags: shell

This is my straightforward function:

```
generate_post_data()
{
  cat <<-EOF
  {"stringData": {}}
EOF
}
```

This is my other function:

```
generate_curl_body()
{
  template=$(generate_post_data $secret_id)
  echo "$template"
  echo "$KVS_VARIABLES" | while read -r key value
  do
    template=$(echo "$template" | jq ".stringData += { \"$key\" : \"$value\" }")
    echo $template
  done
}
```

The output is:

```
#Before while -> {"stringData": {}}
#1 iteration -> { "stringData": { "VAR1": "VAL1" } }
#2 iteration -> { "stringData": { "VAR1": "VAL1", "VAR2": "VAL2" } }
#3 iteration -> { "stringData": { "VAR1": "VAL1", "VAR2": "VAL2", "VAR3": "VAL3" } } 
#After while -> {"stringData": {}}
```

Why `template` variable is not filled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left side of pipe is the subshell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760640/left-side-of-pipe-is-the-subshell#5760832)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered)

Answer (score 0):

It is not filled because the `| while` is executed in subshell. From the [manual page of Bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html) (for example):

> *Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).*

If the shell is Bash, the easy fix is to replace the `echo "$KVS_VARIABLES" |`  with a here-string:

```
while read -r key value; do
  template=$(echo "$template" | jq ".stringData += { \"$key\" : \"$value\" }")
  echo $template
done <<< "$KVS_VARIABLES"
```

If your shell does not accept here-strings, you can always wrap the `while` in a compound command `{ while ... done; echo "$template"; }` and use an extra command substitution:

```
template="$(
  echo "$KVS_VARIABLES" |
  {
    while read -r key value; do
      template=$(
        echo "$template" |
        jq ".stringData += { \"$key\" : \"$value\" }"
      )
    done
    echo "$template"
  }
)"
```

Comment: I'm using `!/usr/bin/env sh`. I'm getting this error message: `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`