# Bash script wait for jobs started in while loop

Tags: bash, shell, asynchronous

How do I wait for background jobs started in a `while read` loop?

I have the following bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
seq 5 | while read i; do
    sleep 1 && echo $i &
done
echo "waiting"
wait
echo "complete"
```

The `wait` doesn't seem to work.

```
sh-5.2$ ./_foo.sh
waiting
complete
sh-5.2$ 3
1
2
5
4
```

A for loop works as expected.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}; do
    sleep 3 && echo $i &
done
echo "waiting"
wait
echo "complete"
```

```
sh-5.2$ ./_foo.sh
waiting
5
1
2
4
3
complete
```

Why doesn't `wait` work in the first case?

Edit: from [Left side of pipe is the subshell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760640/left-side-of-pipe-is-the-subshell), I think this is because each command in a pipeline is started in a subshell, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Do what the [tag:bash] tag you used says, "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.", and it'll tell you about some problems with your script and see "Process Substitution" in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for the main problem you're asking about.

Comment: Regarding "but I'm not sure how to fix it" - I gave you a FAQ URL in my comment that states how to fix it. Just do what it shows you there and use process substitution - `while read i; do
    sleep 3 && echo $i &;
done < <(seq 5);
echo "waiting";
wait;
echo "complete"`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the comment. Thanks! I don't see how this is a duplicate question, though. The original question doesn't contain the answer. I also tried spellcheck.net, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: There are a few ways to do it.  Process substitution is one.  If you've got Bash 4.2 or later (not the default Bash on macOS) you can execute `shopt -s lastpipe` before the pipe and the first version of the code will work.  Another option is to put the loop and the `wait` in the same subprocess: `seq 5 | { while read ...; do ... done; wait; }`

Comment: Not spellcheck.net, shellcheck.net. It won't solve the problem you're asking about, which is why I provided the FAQ which does, but it will solve other problems in your code. That question is about the same problem as you're having, explains why it's a problem, and I provided the FAQ to show how to do what you want. There may be more perfect duplicates but this is a very common question and to be honest I couldn't be bothered wading through all of the relevant answers looking for the perfect one.

Comment: Why is this tagged _zsh_ and _sh_ ? There is neither zsh nor sh involved in your problem.

Comment: [A solution that still uses `while`](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/67d695f5d1fb440363bd04e28c0583e4)

Comment: I see. Thanks everyone for helping